# Three-pin SMD part marked 550B identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Can anyone help me identify this part?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shooting from the hip, maybe [ADR550](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adr550.html#product-overview)? Shunt voltage ref doesn't seem that far-fetched given the PCB layout. You can use these in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

My reference shows it as a: BC550B (BC 550B) - SILICON NPN 50V / 0.2A / 0.5W transistor.

Comment: Quite unlikely, as the designator is U1, implying that it's an integrated circuit of some description.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, the BC550B only ever came in TO-92, while this is SOT-23, or possibly SC-70 (it's hard to tell the dimensions).